# iOS app odd crashes [UINavigationController _startCustomTransition:]

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

I have my app in alpha test, and using fabric to capture the crash logs. I had encountered a crash, and I have the below trace but have no idea what is going on. I tried to reproduce it with Xcode, but hardly can reproduce.

Could any one help on this? or share some ideas?

```
Thread : Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libsystem_platform.dylib       0x0000000197c7d8d4 OSAtomicCompareAndSwap32Barrier + 12
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x0000000197468120 realizeClass(objc_class*) + 100
2  libobjc.A.dylib                0x000000019746c930 lookUpImpOrForward + 224
3  libobjc.A.dylib                0x0000000197477db8 _objc_msgSend_uncached_impcache + 56
4  UIKit                          0x000000018b66bef4 -[UINavigationController _startCustomTransition:] + 972
5  UIKit                          0x000000018b57d630 -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 468
6  UIKit                          0x000000018b57d3fc -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 56
7  UIKit                          0x000000018b57d37c -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 200
8  UIKit                          0x000000018b4c5d2c -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 572
9  QuartzCore                     0x000000018ae1d994 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 168
10 QuartzCore                     0x000000018ae18564 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 320
11 QuartzCore                     0x000000018ae18408 CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 32
12 QuartzCore                     0x000000018ae17c08 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 276
13 QuartzCore                     0x000000018ae1798c CA::Transaction::commit() + 436
14 UIKit                          0x000000018b4c7c48 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 1700
15 CoreFoundation                 0x0000000186cd29ec __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24
16 CoreFoundation                 0x0000000186cd1c90 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 264
17 CoreFoundation                 0x0000000186ccfd40 __CFRunLoopRun + 712
18 CoreFoundation                 0x0000000186bfd0a4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 396
19 GraphicsServices               0x000000018fd975a4 GSEventRunModal + 168
20 UIKit                          0x000000018b52eaa4 UIApplicationMain + 1488
21 MCompass                       0x00000001001631c8 main (main.m:16)
22 libdyld.dylib                  0x0000000197ad2a08 start + 4
```

Comment: Just seeing the same issue reported in the wild for my app. Have you found anything more about it?

Comment: no I didn't see more

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to tell without seeing some more details, but maybe this can help: http://aplus.rs/2013/beware-a-crashing-bug-lurks-with-uinavigationcontroller-transitions/

Comment: I already read that article, but still not help. I just have the logs as I shown to you, and I don't have more. If I have it or got a chance to reproduce with LLDB, I will be less painful.